# How to iterate over a list and compare in python

Tags: python

Here I have a list of integers as follows.

```
print(result)

['0', '0', '1', '0', '88', '38', '45', '1', '22', '25', '19', '32', '1', '34', '']
```

I have three thresholds to check whether each number has reached to that particular level or not. The threshold numbers are as follows.

```
T1=85;
T2=80;
T3=75;
```

I am looking to create the code, but I am not sure where to start.Here is my try.

```
for (int i = 0, i < result.size(); i++):
    prctVal=result[i]
    if prctVal > T1:
        risk = "high" ;
        
    elif prctVal < T3:
        risk = "minor"
        
    else T3<practval<T2:
        risk = "major"     
print(risk)
```

I am ending up with a syntax error.Can some one help me to figure out the issue here?I am new to python.

Comment: use `len(result)` instead of `.size()`, because that doesn't exist

Comment: `for (int i = 0, i < result.size(); i++):` This is not valid Python. There is no ++ operator in Python for example ...

Comment: oh wait, there's more. `for i in range(len(result)):`

Comment: or just can just iterate over the elements themselves: `for i in result`

Comment: `else T3<practval<T2:` There should be no condition on the `else` neither

Comment: The list is full on strings, not integers. Comparing like that will generate an error too

Comment: https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over values in a list, just do `for VAL in LIST`.  It's not necessary to have a separate variable for iterating by index.

Since the values in your list are strings, you need to convert them with the `int` function.

```
for s in result:
    i = int(s)
    if i > T1:
        risk = "high"
    elif i > T2:
        risk = "major"
    elif i > T3:
        risk = "minor"
    else:
        risk = None
    print(risk)
```

Answer (score 0):

All items of `result` list must to be integer (not string)

This is python. not is c#,java or other languages. its syntax is different

```
result = [0, 0, 1, 0, 88, 38, 45, 1, 22, 25, 19, 32, 1, 34]

T1 = 85
T2 = 80
T3 = 75

for prctVal in result:
    
    if prctVal > T1:
        risk = "high"
        
    elif prctVal < T3:
        risk = "minor"
        
    elif T3 <= prctVal <= T2:
        risk = "major"
    

    print(prctVal, risk)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the syntax of python with c what you want can be done as below:

```py
for prctVal in result:
    prctVal = int(prctVal)
    if prctVal > T1:
        risk = "high"
        
    elif prctVal < T3:
        risk = "minor"
        
    else T3<practval<T2:
        risk = "major"
    
    print(prctVal, ":", risk)
```